how would I activate a dialog option onTriggerEnter?
I'm trying to activate the 3rd dialog line from the 'Lines' index when the player enters a trigger zone but currently I can only put one line after the other until there are no more variables in the index, how would I go about stopping the index after Line 2 and then resuming once the player enters a trigger zone?
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class Dialogue : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI textComponent;
    public string[] lines;
    public float textSpeed;

private int index;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    ``textComponent.text = string.Empty;
    startDia();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        if (textComponent.text == lines[index])
        {
            NextLine();
        }
        else
        {
            StopAllCoroutines();
            textComponent.text = lines[index];
        }
    }
}

void startDia()
{
    index = 0;
    StartCoroutine(TypeLine());
}

IEnumerator TypeLine()
{
    foreach (char c in lines[index].ToCharArray())
    {
        textComponent.text += c;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(textSpeed);
    }
}

void NextLine()
{
    if (index < lines.Length - 1)
    {
        index++;
        textComponent.text = string.Empty;
        StartCoroutine(TypeLine());
    }
    else
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}

}
